# Determine if the folder Id is a shared drive folder or a simple drive folder

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Is there a way to determine if the folder is shared Drive folder or not with Google Drive API?

Following is the code I am using to check this:

```
DriveService service = GetService();
var request = service.Files.List();
request.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
IList<File> listFiles = request.Execute().Files;

if (listFiles != null && listFiles.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (var file in listFiles)
   {
       if(file.TeamDriveId == aIdFolder)
       {
          //Yes It's a shared drive folder
       }
   }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Proposed solution works for me:

```
        var listFiles = ListAllFiles(service).Files;

        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in listFiles)
            {
                if (file.Id == aIdFolder && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file.TeamDriveId))
                {
                     //here your result
                    return true;

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [file response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource).

check the driveid property

[image]

I suspect that it would be the same if its a directory thats on a shared drive.   I dont have access to a drive now.  Let me know if it doesnt work.

Comment: HI, thnks for the answer but no match

Comment: what do you mean by match?

Comment: the method is returning  false because.
I debuged and The Driveid or SharedId is the same id of the parent folder inside the shared drive. 
What i want is that from a given folderid i can see if this folder is inside drive or inside SharedDrive